# beautiful soup 4: Use select to get a specify href

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to HTML and Python.

I have the following html fragment:

```
<li data-selenium="aaa" data-isready="true" data-hotelid="1234" data-roomid="12345" class="bbb">
<a id="xxx" data-selenium="" class="yyy" target="_blank" href="/someURL/I_want_to_get">
</a>
</li>
```

There are many class:bbb that contains tags a
I am trying to use **select** function of bs4 to get href in all class bbb.

```
for res in soup.select('.bbb')
  print res.select('a')[0]['href']
```

I success that if the tags a only contain attribute href,
but I get error message if the tags like the above.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then I try to remove that [0] and other error occurs.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers.
```

I have tried many different ways to select but I cannot get it.

I want to use Select instead of findAll.

Is there any method make it works?

Comment: First thing you should check is if the HTML code you provided in your question is the actual one you have in the data files. That HTML is clearly incorrect, because the attributes are outside the tags.

Comment: @Mikk Sorry, Its my carelessness, I have updated that HTML.

Comment: The `select` command is returning a list. If the list is empty, meaning nothing was found, then you can't access the first item of the list.

Comment: @double_j Thank you for your answer. I check is that exist before the select command, it seems work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` command is returning a list. If the list is empty, meaning nothing was found, then you can't access the first item of the list.